# How to convert from date to unix_timestamp using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a time string in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

I would like to convert it to the equivalent of passing the date-string into the mysql unix_timestamp function using Javascript.

I tried parsing the date and passing it into the `Date.UTC()` function but it seems to be giving me different times then what I want. help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are supplying a UTC timestamp and want seconds since 1/1/1970, then:

[...]

#### Edit

Revisited my original answer and didn't like it, the following is better:

```
// Given an ISO8601 UTC timestamp, or one formatted per the OP,
// return the time in seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
function toSecondsSinceEpoch(s) {
  s = s.split(/[-A-Z :\.]/i);
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]));
  return Math.round(d.getTime()/1000);
}
```

Note that the string in the OP isn't ISO8601 compliant, but the above will work with it. If the timestamp is in the local timezone, then:

```
// Given an ISO8601 timestamp in the local timezone, or one formatted per the OP,
// return the time in seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
function toSecondsSinceEpochLocal(s) {
  s = s.split(/[-A-Z :\.]/i);
  var d = new Date(s[0],--s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5]);
  return Math.round(d.getTime()/1000);
}
```

If decimal seconds should be accommodated, a little more effort is required to convert the decimal part to ms.

Comment: Small note: for the revised answer, passing the result of `Date.UTC` to the `Date` constructor and calling `getTime` is unnecessary--`Date.UTC` returns a numeric timestamp directly: `return Math.round(Date.UTC(s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5], s[6]) / 1000);` add to that `Function.prototype.apply` and flooring with bitwise operations (you should probably be flooring instead of rounding), you get `return (Date.UTC.apply(Date, s) / 1000) | 0;`

Comment: @distilledchaos—you can't use apply like that as the second argument needs to be decremented.

Comment: Aww, dang. You're right. I may have gone a bit overboard there.

Answer (score 0):

[Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript) has solved the problem already...

```
// create a new javascript Date object based on the timestamp 
// multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds 
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000); 
// hours part from the timestamp 
var hours = date.getHours(); 
// minutes part from the timestamp 
var minutes = date.getMinutes(); 
// seconds part from the timestamp 
var seconds = date.getSeconds(); 

// will display time in 10:30:23 format 
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

Comment: I'm looking for the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help. But remember you can do this in MySQL using [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateTime)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function. You also have the other way around function that turns unix timestamps into DateTimes: [FROM_UNIXTIME(UnixTimestamp)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building the date object then using .getTime()? This is probably what you want.

eg: Math.round(new Date('2012-03-19 21:01:54').getTime() / 1000)